# How can I display a dashboard on a keyboardless Windows server?

Tags: windows, display

I have a Windows server that is "headless". It's used as a VM and file host. It's managed through PSExec and RDP as it just has power/network.

There is a webpage that serves as a dashboard for health status.

I have a spare monitor that I want to constantly display the dashboard. Rather than set up another machine locked in a cabinet to display this dashboard I'd like to leverage the headless machine.

If I just plug the monitor in I see the Windows Server 2012 login prompt. Is there a way I can display something else to that monitor and continue to manage the server by PSExec and RDP? Essentially I just need to push a bitmap to the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Run netplwiz to set up auto login, and put a shortcut to a webpage in the Startup folder.

This of course is a **HUGE** security risk and I don't recommend doing it, but you asked.  I'm not really sure what you mean by "manage remotely" though...

[Configure a User Account to Log On Automatically on Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx)

Another option is to use something like VNC, which will allow you to remotely control the console session from another PC.  Start your VNC session, open the webpage or do whatever.  This would allow you to easily lock it or logoff.

Comment: Is there a way to still interact with terminal services like I normally do and just feed an image to the monitor?

Comment: Search for mstsc console access. Now that you mention it I think you can start the rdp client (mstsc) with a console switch.

Comment: Hmmm. Looks like the /console switch went away with Windows 2008.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2007/12/17/changes-to-remote-administration-in-windows-server-2008.aspx